# Иконка для ToggleButton

Tags: android

Как сделать такое для ToggleButton? Т.е. чтобы был какой-то фон и иконка? т.е. чтобы фон был к примеру как тут, а вместо OFF и ON были иконки. xml файлы иконок векторных есть, только не понял как их и фон совместить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаете селектор и помещаете в папку *res/drawable*. картинка *toggle_off* соответствует выключенному изображению, *toggle_on* - включенному.

**toggle_selector.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Подключаете этот селектор к виджету:

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/chkState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/toggle_selector"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>
```

атрибуты *textOff* и *textOn* задают текст в переключателе, для выключенного и включенного состояния соответственно. Если он не требуется, то ставим пустые строки

[Пример](https://androidician.wordpress.com/2014/09/24/android-custom-toggle-button-example-ios-like-toggle-buttons/)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь указаны возможности, а не последовательность исполнения. 
Если иконка у вас в папке drawable, то в Activity (если понадобится поменять при работе с приложением)

```
LinearLayout_id.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
toggleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

в layout (фон и цвет по умолчанию)

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_id">

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:background="@drawable/icon"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Речь идет о виджете `ToggleButton`, а не `ImageView`

Comment: исправил, спасибо @pavlofff

Comment: а почему фон (и цвет) дублируется: указывается  в разметке и устанавливается  программно. Для чего это?

Comment: они не дублируется, это варианты коими можно воспользоваться.

Comment: в моем приложении, фон (иконка) и цвет меняются при нажатии на ToggleButton, к примеру. Устанавливаю программно. Возможно это не самый лучший способ, но он работает.

Comment: о том, что это варианты ничего в ответе не сказано, а сказано - в активити написать то то, в разметке - то то , код для активити дублирует атрибуты разметки.

Comment: а в чем собственно тут противоречие? при загрузке приложения кнопка так выглядит - установил человек в Layout, в процессе работы приложения меняется - поменял программно. Здесь указаны возможности, а не последовательность исполнения.

Comment: Ну напишите хотя бы, что если нужно поменять фон или цвет (хотя в вопросе про это ничего нет), то в активити делаем так то. Сейчас у вас все выглядит так, что для того, чтобы установить фон на виджет нужно указывать этот фон и в разметке и через код. Прочитайте сами свой ответ глазами человека, который не знает, как решить проблему в вопросе.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо, в споре рождается истина.